# How can I change syntax highlighting rules for a variable with the lateinit modifier in IntelliJ (Kotlin)?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

IntelliJ highlights `var mutableVariable: String` with an underline.

IntelliJ also highlights `lateinit var mutableVariable: String` with an underline. In practice, my lateinit vars are effectively immutable.

I would like to underline `var`, but not `lateinit var`. Does IntelliJ support this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Non-null fields must be initialised

```
var mutableVariable: String = ""
```

This is valid yet `var` means that variable is mutable. You can't have `lateinit val`

```
lateinit var mutableVariable: String
```

Comment: My question is about IntelliJ's syntax highlighting. Like the graphical display of my code from the IDE b

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood your question. I will check and amend the answer.